# Config Restful api with body and authentication header basic from Mule esb

Tags: spring, mule

I want to export the services to Mule esb.
I have the following types of services.
Type POST
http://10.1.3.193:8080/HRMS/remoting/kpidata/login
Type GET
http://10.1.3.193:8080/HRMS/remoting/kpiDiemhieuqua/getFileXaydung/124/2019/NAM/GENCO

I config service login on MULE:

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="0.0.0.0" port="8081" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration" basePath="/ESB"/>
<http:request-config name="HTTP_Request_Configuration_outboundWS" host="10.1.3.193" port="8080" doc:name="HTTP Request Configuration" basePath="/HRMS/remoting/kpidata"/>
<flow name="myFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/login" doc:name="Inbound HTTP" allowedMethods="POST"/>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/><set-property propertyName="Content-Type" value="application/json" doc:name="Set Outbound Header"/>
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration_outboundWS" path="/login" method="POST" doc:name="POST WebService"/>

</flow>
```

Java code service

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = { "Content-type=application/json" })
public @ResponseBody KpiCaytochuc postLogin(@RequestBody final UserLogin user, ModelMap model) {
    System.out.println(user);
    KpiCaytochuc kpiCayToChuc = null;
    return kpiCayToChuc;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/getFileXaydung/{idDonvi}/{nam}/{kybaocao}/{nhom}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<KpiDgCthq> getFileXaydung(@PathVariable("idDonvi") Integer idDonvi,
        @PathVariable("nam") Integer nam, @PathVariable("kybaocao") String kybaocao,
        @PathVariable("nhom") String nhom) {
    KpiDmKyapdung kyapdung = dmServices.getByYear(nam, idDonvi);
    KpiDgCthq ddg = baocaoServices.getHtnhiemvu(idDonvi, nhom, kyapdung.getId());
    ddg.setKpiDgCthqgiaos(null);
    return new ResponseEntity<KpiDgCthq>(ddg, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

Run Mule 
500 No serializer found for class org.glassfish.grizzly.utils.BufferInputStream and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationConfig.Feature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) ) (org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException). (org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException).

[image: Run restlet client]

[image: Run Mule]

Please help me

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, I have seen this error happening when there is a response type mismatch between what's defined in RAML and the actual response type.